# PHP - Function to read and write a TXT file

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm making a function on WordPress to get the content of the robots.txt file. If the file doesn't exist, create it with default content. I will use it for my options page. Well, this is my code, it should work almost creating the file, but it doesn't:

```
function get_robots($robots_file) {

$robots_file = get_home_path() . 'robots.txt'; //The robots file.
$dir = get_home_path(); //The root directory

if(is_file($robots_file)){
    $handle = fopen($robots_file, "r");
    $robots_content = fread($handle, filesize($robots_file));        
    fclose($handle);

} else {
    $default_content = "User-agent: *\nDisallow:";
    chmod($dir, 0777);
    $handle = fopen($robots_file, "w+");
    $robots_content = fwrite($handle, $default_content);        
    fclose($handle);

}

chmod($dir, 0744);
return $robots_content;

}
```

I'm not sure if the problem is `is_file`, or the `fopen($robots_file, "w+"` (should it be "r"?) after the `else`. And I'm not sure about the permissions. Is the 777 needed? Is the 744 the default for the root directory of WordPress?

And I use the `return` to use it as variable later; I suppose the `fopen` is already creating the file. Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you're wondering which function argument to use, then you should start by looking at the function documentation: http://php.net/fopen they're clearly documented there. Oh, and doing chmod 744 on a directory will  probably break it for all other users. removing execution permissions on the dir removes the ability to list its contents. it doesn't remove the ability to read files in it, as long as you know what the filename is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing, I would use completely different functions, you have `file_put_contents()` and `file_get_contents()` for such simple operations.

So possible simpler solution is:

```
function get_robots() {

$robots_file = get_home_path() . 'robots.txt'; //The robots file.


if(file_exists($robots_file)){
    return file_get_contents($robots_file);

} else {
    $default_content = "User-agent: *\nDisallow:";
    file_put_contents($robots_file, $default_content);
    return $default_content;
}

}
```

I don't see any point to pass `$robots_file` as function argument so I removed it. You should check if this code simple works.

I also don't see any reason to change `$dir` permissions as you showed in your code. It should be rather set manually and you definitely shouldn't change your root directory permission in such function.

**EDIT**

Because this function uses `get_home_path()` and this one is available probably only on admin panel you have to do it in different way. You may add the following code to the end of your index.php file:

```
function get_robots($path)
{
    $robots_file = $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'robots.txt'; //The robots file.
    if(file_exists($robots_file)){
        return file_get_contents($robots_file);

    } else {
        $default_content = "User-agent: *\nDisallow:";
        file_put_contents($robots_file, $default_content);
        return $default_content;
    }
}

get_robots(getcwd());
```

(Of course if you want, you may move `get_robots()` function to some other files.

However you should consider if this is the best approach. You will run this function each time your site will be viewed and it's tiny waste (in fact you will probably want to create robots.txt file just once). You could for example create `robots.php` file and if you want to run it you can run `http://yourwordpressurl/robots.php`. It's of course your call.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I suppose loading the code the file should be created, because it doesn't exist, but it's not working. The code is located on functions.php (WordPress). Tested it on localhost.

Comment: Do you run this function anywhere? You need to add `get_robots();` to execute this function

Comment: Omg, that was the big fail xD. Btw, it's returning `Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_home_path()`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks again. That's great and it works perfect. Also, it's really a good idea to use the function in an external file. I'm gonna think about when it's the best moment to run the function.